# Why is my background image not showing when location changes (after zipping and opening file)?

Tags: html, css

**Problem**

My problem is that my background images don't appear when opening the HTML document after zipping and unzipping the folder.

I have a html-file that includes the following line within the style tag:

`background: url(star.svg) no-repeat 10% 40%, url(star.svg) no-repeat 90% 40%, linear-gradient(#e7e7e7, #a7a7a7);`

Which works fine when running in VS Code or clicking and opening in Chrome. The star.svg is in the same folder as we are currently in. However, when I zip the project and reopen it the stars no longer show, as the filepath has changed.

**Attempts at a solution**

When I looked up the issue on SO the problem people was having is that they had a seperate stylesheet and the path wasn't relative to the CSS file, but I have everything in the html-file. However, I have one folder that holds all the files and as I understand it url(star.svg) should point to the current folder no matter what the circumstance.

Comment: Are you actually unzipping all contents of the zip file, or do you open your html file directly from within the zip file?

Comment: I open the html directly from within the zip file. I just tried dragging the folder out and opening it then and it works fine. Thank you for your help, but why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when opening a file from within a zip file (without unzipping it explicitly), a temporary copy of the file is created. This file will be located at a temporary path. Since only the opened file is present at this location, references to other files in the zip file won't work.
When you open your html file from within the zip, just look at the address bar of your browser and you will see the location of the temporary file.

The solution in this case is to simply unzip all relevant files and open them from the unzipped location.

Comment: That's great to know. Thank you for your time!